# Como fazer um construtor igual ao do QObject?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, qt

Surgindo uma nova dúvida de uma questão antiga, quero saber como criar uma classe igual ao `QObject`. Basicamente, quero saber:

- Como fazer um copy constructor que não aceite "assignment operators"?
- Como fazer uma classe que possa deletar outras?
- Como fazer uma classe parecida com o `QObject`?

Comment: O que significa "fazer um copy constructor que não aceite assignment operators"? Não entendi.

Comment: `Object ObjetoB = ObjetoA`.

Comment: @LucasHenrique ou vc permite construção de cópia ou não permite, não tem como remover parcialmente a funcionalidade de construção por cópia, desabilitando a sintaxe com `=` mas ao mesmo tempo permitindo a inicialização direta `Object ObjetoB{ObjetoA}`. Você pode, como @guilherme-bernal fez, é não ter construtor de cópia e ter outros construtores.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os QObject do Qt foram feitos com o intuito de funcionar na heap sem tanta dificuldade com o manejo de memória. Eles são não copiáveis (construtor de cópia privado ou deletado). Além disso cada objeto pode ter um parente terá zero ou mais filhos. Setar o parente de um objeto significa se adicionar à lista de filhos do parente. O destrutor de cada objeto deleta todos os filhos. Note que se um objeto for criado fora da heap, não é recomendado que ele tenha um parente, já que este tentará chamar `delete` no filho em seu destrutor.

A implementação é similar a essa:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Object {
    std::vector<Object*> _children; // No QObject é usado um QList aqui
    Object* _parent = nullptr;
public:
    Object(Object* parent=nullptr) { setParent(parent); }
    Object(const Object&) = delete;

    void setParent(Object* parent) {
        if (_parent) {
            std::vector<Object*>& vec = _parent->_children;
            vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), this), vec.end()); // remove this
        }
        _parent = parent;
        if (_parent) {
            _parent->_children.push_back(this);
        }
    }

    virtual ~Object() { // destrutor deve ser virtual, já que é uma base abstrata
        setParent(nullptr); // Se remove do seu parente
        for (Object* child : _children)
            delete child; // deleta todos os filhos e, por recursão, seus filhos
    }
};
```

Comment: @LucasHenrique faltou um `_` ali no destrutor. Corrigido.

Comment: O Qt permite que se declare objetos na pilha. É perfeitamente possível fazer `QObject a; QObject b(&a); QObject c(&b);`. Os destrutores são chamados em ordem inversa à declaração, cada um deles removendo o objeto destruído da lista de filhos do pai.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser Esse é um caso particular em que a ordem de destruição remove os objetos dos parentes antes que eles tenham a chance de `delete`alos. Observe `QObject a; QObject b; a.setParent(&b);`. Crash!

Comment: @LucasHenrique O melhor exemplo disso é o próprio Qt. Permitir alocar objetos na heap sem se preocupar em destruir-los, criando uma estrutura hierarquica. É quase como se fosse um tipo de coletor de lixo.

Comment: @LucasHenrique O Qt deixa o construtor de cópia privado em alguns casos, mas implementa em outros, principalmente em classes que representam recursos compartilhados, como o  `QImage`. Você pode criar cópias deles, embora internamente todos apontem para o mesmo recurso.

Comment: @C.E.Gesser Importante notar que a `QImage` não é um `QObject`. Assim como acontece com todos os containers e com as strings. Essas classes fazem compartilhamento de dados então são bastante leves e podem ser copiadas em todo o lugar. Nem faz sentido que sejam alocadas na heap.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Verdade, essa distinção não é muito clara no Qt. Você tem objetos com semântica compartilhada, como o QImage, cuja cópia cria mais referências, outros com semântica exclusiva, como os derivados do QObject, não copiáveis, e ainda objetos pequenos, como QPoint, com semântica de valor. E você só consegue saber como é qual pela documentação ou olhando o código.

Comment: Se eu tivesse uma classe derivada por hierarquia, como eu poderia passá-la no parâmetro "Object"?

Comment: `class B : public QObject {...}; QObject a(new B);` isso?

Answer (score 3):

O QObject tem dentro dele uma lista de filhos. Algo como:

```
class QObject {
  std::vector<QObject*> children;
  QObject *parent;
};
```

O construtor basicamente guarda o pai e adiciona o objeto à sua lista

```
QObjec(QObject *parent) : parent(parent) {      
  if (parent)
    parent->children.push_back(this);
}
```

A magia fica no destrutor. Ele tem que destruir todos os filhos. Isso é fácil. Mas ele tem que cuidar caso ele seja filho de alguém, precisa se remover da lista dele para evitar um `delete` duplo.

```
virtual ~QObject() {
  if (parent) 
    parent->removeChild(this);

  for (unsigned i=0; i<children.size(); ++i) {
    delete children[i];
  }
}
```

O destrutor deve ser virtual, pois na hora de invocá-lo queremos que seja chamado o destrutor da classe correta, e apenas o de QObject.
Para remover-se da lista do pai, algo assim poderia ser feito:

```
QObject::removeChild(QObject *child) {
  std::vector<QObject*>::iterator iter = std::remove(children.begin(), children.end(), child);
  children.erase(iter, children.end());
}
```

Só não entendi muito ainda o que você quis dizer com construtor que não aceite atribuições.